# Rewarded Video in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, flurry, chartboost

I planned to add the rewarded video in my Android app which I am building in LibGdx framework. I have checked the Google mobile Ads SDK document in the below Link. Though the link explainations are clear, there is a bug in it. Please refer the attched reply from Google groups[Reply from Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/PxhazBh9_SM)

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd)

I just need a reliable network with mediation support. Hence I tried Mopub. They told that they are not with the LibGdx framework, and is therefore not able to offer support for it.

### Question

What is the better way to add the Rewarded Video Ad in LibGdx + Android App ?
Anybody tried it so far ? Could you please help to setup that in my Android App ?

Comment: I have tried both chartboost and adcolony, they both work fine with my libgdx ios+android app

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do it. I am very much in need of a guide to that.  How are you doing that ? Via Admob Mediation of direct implementation

Comment: I directly implemented the sdk using the examples provided by adcolony/chartboost. It's not that hard.

Comment: In LibGdx+Android we usually for Admob we used to use AdView to show Ads. Is there is anything specific like that.. ?

Comment: no need for any special view, chartboost/adcolony both use new activities for the ads. Which makes it very easy to implement. You'll need maybe 10 lines of code. Read on here: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK/wiki/Showing-V4VC-Videos

Comment: Super! how about chartboost ? How you established mediation ? you did mediation in your program